# How do I tell magallanes to execute composer with --no-dev?

Tags: php, deployment, composer-php

I'm trying to deploy a PHP web application using [Magallanes](http://magephp.com/).

This is my actual task config:

```
tasks:
  pre-deploy:
    - composer/install
  on-deploy:
    - filesystem/link-shared-files:
        linked_folders:
          - web/fileadmin
          - web/uploads
          - web/typo3temp
          - web/typo3conf/l10n
  post-release:
    - general/manually:
      - vendor/bin/typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure
      - vendor/bin/typo3cms install:generatepackagestates --activate-default=true
      - vendor/bin/typo3cms cache:flush true
      - vendor/bin/typo3cms database:updateschema "*.add,*.change"
      - vendor/bin/typo3cms cache:warmup
  post-deploy:
```

While using:

```
pre-deploy:
        - composer/install
```

Composer will always be called with `composer install --dev`. Is there a way to call composer with `--no-dev` instead of `--dev`?

PS: I already tried `- composer/install --no-dev`, which generates the following error:

> Starting Pre-Deployment tasks:
> Task "Composer/installNoDev" not found.

**Update**
Because I needed some more parameters, I used `general/manually`. My solution is now:

```
tasks:
  pre-deploy:
    - general/manually:
        - php7.0 /usr/local/bin/composer install --no-dev --no-progress --optimize-autoloader
```

But on the other hand my, original question was something different. So Chris's answere seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
pre-deploy:
  - composer/install: {dev: false}
```

I couldn't find this in the documentation, but [the source references a `'dev'` parameter](https://github.com/andres-montanez/Magallanes/blob/dd79eca75f8bc5ee1f970ad5853c3fa1df96e0fd/Mage/Task/BuiltIn/Composer/InstallTask.php#L18-L28) that seems to control `--dev` / `--no-dev`:

```
public function run()
{
    $dev = $this->getParameter('dev', true);
    return $this->runCommand($this->getComposerCmd() . ' install' . ($dev ? ' --dev' : ' --no-dev'));
}
```

The documentation is [a bit more helpful about setting parameters](http://magephp.com/#cookbook-task-configuration), but I'm not sure if it will correctly read `false` as a Boolean value.

Comment: Didn't tried that. Now I needed some more parameters then just `--no-dev`. 

What I used is in my Post above under *Update*.